# Why are these particles slower with CSS3 GPU transforms?

Tags: javascript, css, gpu

Why does [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/jbeuckm/5922491) run slower when the position is set by translate3d(x,y,z)?

My guess is that every change to the CSS requires a recalculation of the style, which is less expensive when the element isn't being sent to the GPU. Is there a way to do the dynamic transitions that I need without recalculating the style?

I'm interested in running in a WebView on iOS and Android. Is CSS3 the only option for accessing the GPU? Is there a way to use the GPU to increase performance here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to use the GPU for accelerated drawing on mobile webviews is via the `<Canvas>` element. This similar example is able to move four times as many particles at a similar framerate:

[Canvas Particles](http://bl.ocks.org/jbeuckm/5971531)